Request for a General Proof of the Superposition Theorem in Circuit Theory
I’ve been studying circuit theory, and I came across the superposition theorem, which states that in a linear circuit with multiple independent sources, the response in any element of the circuit is the sum of the responses caused by each independent source acting alone (while all other sources are replaced by their internal impedances).
I understand the theorem intuitively and can apply it to solve problems, but I’d like to understand it at a deeper level. Could someone explain or provide a general proof of the superposition theorem?
Specifically, I’d love to see:
A mathematical derivation or proof that applies to any linear circuit.

Ronald E. Scott, Linear Circuits, New York: Addison-Wesley, 1960. He went in to prove it for dependent sources, as well.

LTI Linear time-invariant circuit.

Physics SE - Is there a formal proof for the superposition theorem?

If you understand the concept of 'linear', then it more or less proves itself, it's basically a tautology.
The key insight is perhaps that you do not do the disruptive-sounding thing of  all other sources are replaced by their internal impedances. Instead, you make all sources variable, and simply set the other sources to zero, while keeping all the sources, their impedances, and their positions intact. This achieves the same thing as that problematic phrase above, without disrupting the circuit.
Voltage sources will continue to be short-circuits. That is, the voltage across their terminals will stay at what they are set to, whether 0 or some non-zero value, and any current can flow without altering that. Similarly, current sources will remain open-circuit, allowing any voltage across their terminals, while continuing to force the set current through them.
If you set all the sources to zero, then [0,0,0,0 ...] will be a valid solution for your network. Now adjust any source to a non-zero value. It's a solution. Linearity ensures that when you adjust another source, all points respond with the sum of the excitations.
Just make sure you do have a linear circuit. Any non-linearity, like a diode as one of the components, destroys the independence of the sources.

To me, the superposition theorem is a direct and logical consequence of Kirchhoffs current law:
When two currents meet in a common node, the resulting current is the sum of both contributing currents. And, of course, the result of such an addition is not time-dependent, which means that the two currents can exist at the same time - or (during superposition) one after another.
==================
EDIT
As requested by Carl, in the following an example is presented to show the similarity (connection) between KCL and Superposition.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Task description: Find I3 as a function of V1 and V2.
1.) Calculation: According to KCL we have I3=I1+I2=Vs/R3=(V1-Vs)/R1 + (V2-Vs)/R2
After solving for Vs and dividing by R3.......we get:
I3=Vs/R3=V1 * [R2/(R1R2 + R2R3 + R1R3)] + V2 * [R1/(R1R2 + R2R3 + R1R3)]
2.) Alternative: Applying superposition we get
I3=I1+I2=V1/[(R2||R3) + R1] + V2/[(R1||R3) + R2]
When we insert   R2||R3=R2R3/(R2+R3)  and  R1||R3=R1R3/(R1+R3) we get, of course, the same expression for I3 as caculated with KCL.
3.) Conclusion: Both methods are based on the same principle (KCL): I1+I2-I3=0 .
3.1) In the first case we have calculated the sum of two currents (I1 and I2) resulting from two driving voltages (at the same time). This calculation was based on Ohms law using the node voltage Vs as an auxiliary variable.
3.2) In the second case we have calculated the sum of two currents (I1 and I2) resulting from two driving voltages (one after another). This calculation was based on Ohms law without the necessity to use an auxiliary variable (Vs). Therefore, this method is more simple.

Kirchoff's current law is always valid, even in circuits with dependent sources, and nonlinear components. Source superposition can only be applied to linear circuits, and only indepdent sources can be turned off. I personally don't see the connection between source superposition and KCL.

@ Carl - I cannot understand the background and the reasoning of your comment. Simple question: Something wrong with my contribution? Please, be specific. More than that, it has been shown that superposition can be applied even for dependent sources within the network.

@ Carl - if you have problems to "see the connection between source superposition and KCL" I could verify my position with a simple example.

If you have an example I’m interested in seeing it. Just for the record, I did not downvote this answer.

Application of node voltage analysis results in a matrix equation of a particular form where all sources are in a column vector. The solution for any quantity can be written as a ratio of determinants. I believe you can prove superposition from the properties of determinants.
NV analysis uses only KCL and KVL.
